# RxJava2 subscribe stops observing after a while but continues when flowable completes

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm having a hard time understanding the behaviour of the following code sample;

```java
    Flowable<String> f = Flowable.just(1)
            .flatMap(it -> Flowable.create(e -> {

                for(int i = 1; i < 1001; ++i) {
                    log.info("Emitting: " + i);
                    if(i % 10 == 0) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    e.onNext(i);
                }

                e.onComplete();
            }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER))
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

    f.subscribe(val -> {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        log.info("Observing: " + val);
    });

    Thread.sleep(1000000);
```

The code works OK until 128 items are observed by the `subscribe` call. Emit and observe are in parallel. But after that, Flowable continues to emit items (which are queued somewhere obviously) but no item is observed until all 1000 of items are emitted. After all 1000 items are emitted, then the rest of items (> 128) are observed at once.

This looks to be related to backpressure bufferSize of 128 but still I would expect the emit and observe to be in parallel for the whole 1000 items, because observer is obviously not slower than the emitter. Is there something I'm missing here? What should I do to fix the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a same pool deadlock between create and [subscribeOn](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#subscribeOn(io.reactivex.Scheduler)):

> If there is a `create(FlowableOnSubscribe, BackpressureStrategy)` type source up in the chain, it is recommended to use `subscribeOn(scheduler, false)` instead to avoid same-pool deadlock because requests may pile up behind a eager/blocking emitter.

```
//...
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io(), false)
//...
```

**Edit:**

> I tried the original example (plus your suggested fix) by replacing Flowable.create with a Flowable.range but I didn't encounter a problem. Can you give an example when problems may occur?

```
Flowable.range(1, 10)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io(), false)
    .doOnNext(v -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()))
    .observeOn(Schedulers.single(), false, 1)
    .blockingSubscribe();
```

This initially prints `RxCachedThreadScheduler-1` then `RxSingleScheduler-1` 9 times because `observeOn`'s replenishment request will run on the single scheduler instead of routed back to the io scheduler. Try this with subscribeOn true.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it should be the default behaviour? It was really hard for me to track this down...

Comment: No, because this affects only `Flowable.create` and would disrupt the other sources as for them, subscribeOn has to pin the emission to the particular scheduler. With an imperative `create`, the fact you are "blocking" the emission thread, there is no need nor the ability to go back to that thread triggered by downstream requests.

Comment: So, what I understand is that `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io(), false)` can cause problems with other streams, right? I have a common place where I have that `subscribeOn` call and my sources may differ, some with `Flowable.create` and some not. I tried the original example (plus your suggested fix) by replacing `Flowable.create` with a `Flowable.range` but I didn't encounter a problem. Can you give an example when problems may occur?

Comment: Thanks for the example. However, when I have the `observeOn` before `doOnNext` then it's working the same way regardless of `subscribeOn` with true or false. In my use case I always call `subscribeOn` and then `observeOn` immediately after that. So for my use case your fix looks good and hopefully won't cause any problems with sources without `Flowable.create`.